# Auto Generate Patient ID Using Two Columns

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, vb.net-2010

In the table Screening i have StudyID. The StudyID is a combination of two numbers StudyType( For Cases = KNH-01, For Controls = KNH-02) and Serealized 5 digit number (00001,00002). So the screening table looks like this;

`ID  StudyID        Age
 1   KNH-01/00001   22
 2   KNH-01/00002   15
 3   KNH-02/00001   4
 4   KNH-02/00002   28`

Currently the StudyID numbers are manually saved in a log book and I would wish to automate the process of generating the StudyID numbers. I have created a table to manage StudyID

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PatientID](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PatientType] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [PatientNumber] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__PatientI__3214EC2739E294A9] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I am unable to get last `PatientNumber`  based on the `PatientType` my intention is to have a button at the vb.net front end when a user clicks to generate StudyID it checks the last given number within a studytype adds 1 to it and loads to form. e.g. `KNH-01/00003` or `KNH-02/00003`. If you have a better Idea i will really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my personal favorite way of solving such requirements involves using a computed column and a UDF to compute the values in that column.

So first, you create the UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GenerateStudyID (
    @PatientType varchar(5),
    @id int
)
RETURNS char(11)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT @PatientType +'/'+ RIGHT('00000', CAST(COUNT(*) as char(5)), 5)
        FROM [dbo].[PatientID] 
        WHERE PatientType = @PatientType 
        AND Id <= @id
    )
END
GO
```

Then, you add the computed column to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PatientID]  
ADD StudyID as dbo.GenerateStudyID (PatientType, id)
GO
```

**Please note** that you can't use this method if you need this column to be persisted, since once you will delete a record the values will change.